# Tizen Web SDK: How to remotely debug (web inspector) web app running on watch (Galaxy)?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I'm wondering how (and if it's even possible) to remotely debug an app, written with the web SDK, running on the Samsung Galaxy Watch?

I'm able to:

- connect to the watch with the Device Manager (logs show up, etc)
- install and run the app on the watch
- debug an app in the watch emulator (so I can confirm the Javascript debugger is working)

When I try to debug on the watch itself:

- it correctly installs the app
- sets up the port forwarding, eg build console has: Forwarded port: local(34473) -> remote(34473)
- launches the Chrome Dev Tools, eg build console has: Opening the Web Inspector: http://127.0.0.1:34473/devtools/inspector.html?ws=127.0.0.1:34473/devtools/page/3c071e56-9c65-494f-a22a-0011ea747859

...but the Chrome page is blank. Reloading the page makes no difference, still stays blank.

Googling around I've found very little. This forum post (https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/web-inspector-not-working-remote-device?langswitch=en) describes the same issue, but the answer is not useful: the provided link shows how to run the app (which works), not how to remotely debug.

Any help would be appreciated. At this point I'm not sure it's even possible.

Watch is running Tizen 4.0.0.1, and using Tizen Studio 3.0.

Comment: Would you please share your Galaxy Watch's FW version ?

Comment: Good point, adding version info.

Comment: where is your fw version ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the firmware version. It's running build R810XXU1BRK3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue before.
I solved the answer from HyunJun Jung of this this forum.
**https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/web-inspector-not-working-remote-device?langswitch=en**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Finally a way to my normal chrome rather than their buggy bundled one.

Comment: glad it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

After much searching I've found the way to solve the Blank issue with Chrome DevTools in this post: [Chrom devtools insepctor showing blank white screen while debugging with Samsung TV Tizen Web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182668/chrom-devtools-insepctor-showing-blank-white-screen-while-debugging-with-samsung)

Basically

- Create the folder `c:\Temp` if it does not exist already
- Go to Window > Preferences > Tizen Studio > Web > Chrome -> Extra parameters
- Add `--enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-blink-features=CustomElementsV0 --user-data-dir=c:\Temp`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in the past. I noticed that Chrome since version 54 started block some process and console tab is blank. I found out that jakubkozlowsk@hotmail.com prepared extension [Tizen Console Fix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tizen-console-fix/hfpknnioheddhjmjhchindnmcoadmekl?hl=en) which fix this problem. I'm started using it and it helped me