# Chrome devtools inspector showing blank white screen while debugging with Samsung TV Tizen Web application

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, javascript-debugger, tizen-studio

I'm debugging `Samsung TV Tizen Web Application` with `Tizen Studio 3.6` and `Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. But `Chrome Inspector` showing black screen.

**Chrome path config :**

[image: chrome path]

**Chrome blank screen :**

[image: Chrome blank screen]

Please help me out from this issue.

Comment: facing the same problem and so frustrated with that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution actually it is because Chrome has launched its new version 80.0.3987.100 on the 11th of Feb and because of this version is not compatible with Samsung Tizen IDE so to resolve this you have to download the old version of the older version.

here is the link to download older chrome version 
[https://www.filepuma.com/download/google_chrome_64bit_79.0.3945.79-24169/][1]

After downloading disable the chrome to update itself and then it will work fine with Tizen studios.

Answer (score 9):

This is compatibility issue due to upstream change in chrome 80 version.
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/h-JwMiPUnuU/sl79aLoLBQAJ
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685385

It will be resolved in the next release of Tizen Studio. 
Until then, if you use the options below, inspector will be launched properly.

Go to Window > Preferences > Tizen Studio > Web > Chrome -> Extra parameters :
add "--enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-blink-features=CustomElementsV0 --user-data-dir=c:\Temp"

Comment: This did the trick without needing to down grade or download different chrome versions. just adding '--enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-blink-features=CustomElementsV0' did the trick on my mac.

Comment: On my fresh installation of Tizen Studio 4.1 the `--enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-blink-features=CustomElementsV0` parameters were already present. I still added the user-data-dir. It did not solve the problem for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to download Chromium but there is a trick to setting it as the debugger.
Download https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/706915/

> chrome-mac.zip

or find Chromium somewhere else. Ensure its version 79.

1. Important: Be sure to open chromium and allow in privacy and security preferences. Make sure Chromium opens before proceeding.
2. Open Tizen Studio and go to

> Tizen Studio > preferences

from menu bar
Open

> Tizen Studio > Web > Chrome

in preferences

3. Change location to look like this:

> /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium

4. Note: If you browse to file, you will not be able to get to this
   path. You can see path by right clicking on the Chromium file and
   showing package contents
5. Apply and close

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window > Preferences > Tizen Studio > Web > Chrome -> Extra parameters > input the below command > Apply

--no-first-run --activate-on-launch --no-default-browser-check --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --disable-translate --proxy-auto-detect --proxy-bypass-list=127.0.0.1 --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-blink-features=CustomElementsV0 --user-data-dir=tmpFix

Launch the application.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore blank page and first visit

```
http://localhost:9222/json
```

then check devtoolsFrontendUrl from the JSON and go to

```
http://localhost:9222/
```

I wrote a post about how to setup Chrome Remote Debugging which covers this fix https://devforth.io/blog/chrome-remote-debugging-setup/