# Chrome devtools inspector showing blank white screen while debugging Tizen Web application

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, tizen-web-app, javascript-debugger, tizen-studio

The problem described here

[Chrome devtools inspector showing blank white screen while debugging with Samsung TV Tizen Web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182668/chrome-devtools-inspector-showing-blank-white-screen-while-debugging-with-samsun)

still exists (or exists again).

The solutions from that question to add extra parameters do not work for Tizen Studio 4.1 and Chromium 88.0.4324.150.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a previous chrome build here:

- Windows

  https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/706915/
- Mac

  https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/706915/
- Linux

  https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/706915/

Unfortunately this is just a workaround and not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case downgrading Chromium was not sufficient.
Deleting **author-signature.xml** and **signature1.xml**  files from Tizen project folder and restarting TV has worked for me.
(I am using Chromium 68)